# SD card extension for a mid-2012 15" MacBook Pro?

Tags: data-storage, sd-card

I find it a very interesting options to extend my MacBook's storage capacity by permanently adding an SD card. One possible solution would be the [Transcend Jetdrive Lite](http://sg.transcend-info.com/apple/jetdrivelite/). There are also other extension cards and microSD adapters available. I tried [this product i](http://theminidrive.theshoppad.com/#/product/theminidrive-pro)n the past but it broke within weeks.

Can you recommend a product / solution for my Macbook Pro (non-Retina, mid 2012)? The extension should have at least 128 GB additional storage, and it doesn't matter if it is a microSD adapter or a custom SD card as long as it doesn't stick out of the laptop case.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic since half of this question is a product review: *Do you have any experience* is incredibly opinion-based, and is more or less not a good fit here, as we are about recommendations. It's also quite broad: what size of SD card? Micro SD? This need to be more specific.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Edited the question. Hope the wording suits you better.

Comment: I think the specific advantage of those drives is they're a wierd form factor that dosen't stick out. Its a full sd card with a bit lopped off.